# Create custom trigger to back load files partitioned by day in Azure Data factory

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have csv files in an azure blob storage partitioned by day
(eg. 2022/08/14/name_of_file_hh_mm_ss.csv). I a want to create a custom trigger scheduled to run for a particular period of time (eg. 01/01/2022 to 18/01/2022). My pipeline is expecting the name of the file as a parameter to process the file.

Comment: I think that you're looking for an [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html) for specific times, and not a trigger? Triggers only operate on table before (and/or after) insert/update/delete.

Comment: How will this work with triggering a pipeline in azure data factory? @PaulT.

Comment: I'm not sure how MySQL is integrated with azure, but having the question tagged with MySQL, figured the link info would be the way to go based on what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Schedule Trigger` Azure Data Factory.

As shown in below screenshot you can mention `Start Date - 01/01/2022` and `End Date - 18/01/2022`

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers